# adb.exe for eclipse got deleted from sdk folder by antivirus

Tags: android, eclipse

The ADB.EXE file for eclipse got deleted from the SDK folder by the AVG antivirus. What can I do to get the file back?

Answer (score 2):

Just download **Minimal ADB and Fastboot** from [here](http://x.chip.de/intern/dl/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.chip.de%2Fdownloads%2Fc1_downloads_auswahl_62500184.html%3Ft%3D1450963366%26v%3D3600%26s%3D1952d0a7b4f520cb5241931549675b8a&pageLayout=withinstaller%7Ce50) and copy the *adb.exe* from the archive.